# ASP.NET MVC SignalR Client methods not invoked in separate project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I have to two separate asp.net projects on the same server. All correct SignalR nuget packages are installed as far as I know on both projects. One is the ChatServer and another is a ChatClient. Both are DotNetNuke  projects.

The second project DOES know about signalR because OnConnected in Server project gets triggered when running client project and the client user is inserted as online (through the server OnConnected method).

When the sever comes online (by launching server project)the method in the client "getonlineusers" does not get triggered though.
But if I refresh the client, the server does show as offline. But I shouldnt have to refresh.

I am probably missing something not sure if I am creating a proxy correctly for the client project, any help would be greatly appreciated.

How do you connect a client separate project to the project that has the hub with SignalR?

In the ChatServer project:

```
public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }


public class ChatSupportHub : Hub
    {
        private ChatServerManager CSM { get; set; }

        private int UserID { get; set; }

        //private UserInfo CurrentUser { get; set; }
        public ChatSupportHub()
        {
            CSM = new ChatServerManager();
            //CurrentUser = DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.UserController.Instance.GetCurrentUserInfo();
        }


        public override Task OnConnected()
        {

            int outNumber = -1;

            Online user = new Online();
            User dbUser = new User();

            var userid = Context.QueryString["userid"];

            bool success = Int32.TryParse(userid, out outNumber);

            string connID = Context.ConnectionId;

            if (success)
            {
                user.ID = outNumber;
                dbUser = CSM.GetUser(outNumber);
                UserID = outNumber;
            }

            user.ConnectionID = connID;
            user.Type = dbUser.TypeID.HasValue ? CSM.GetUserType((int) dbUser.TypeID) : null;
            user.ShowOnline = true;

            CSM.AddOnlineUser(user);

            var onlineUsers = CSM.GetOnlineUsers();

            var clients = Clients.Caller;

            string onlineUserJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(onlineUsers);

            clients.getonlineusers(dbUser.Name, onlineUserJSON);

            return base.OnConnected();
        }


        public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
        {
            var username = Context.User.Identity.Name;

            int userID = CSM.GetUserId(username);

            CSM.RemoveOnlineUser(userID);


            return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
        }
    }
```

And the View index page of the ChatServer project:

```
<script src="~/myServertProjectPath/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>

<script>

    $(function () {

        // set up the hub connection
        var hub = $.connection.chatSupportHub;
        $.connection.hub.qs = "userid=" + @Model.CurrentUserInfo.UserID.ToString();

        hub.client.getonlineusers = function (currentUsername, onlineUsers) {

            if (onlineUsers) {
                console.log('There are users online and one is: ' + currentUsername);
            }
        }

        $.connection.hub      
            .start()          
            .done(function () {

            })
   });
```

And same thing in the separate client project for the view:

```
<script src="~/myClientProjectPath/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>

<script>
    $(function () {
        connect();
    });

    function connect() {

        hub = $.connection.chatSupportHub;
        $.connection.hub.qs = "userid=" + @Model.CurrentUserInfo.UserID.ToString();


        hub.client.getonlineusers = function (currentUsername, onlineUsers) {
            if (onlineUsers) {
                console.log ("Hello from the separate project.");
            }
        }

        $.connection.hub
            .start()
            .done(function () {

            })
    }
</script>
```